# Xcode 4.5 UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, ios6, scrollview, xcode4.5

I'd like to add a scrollview to my project.

I've added the following code in my file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 830)];
}
```

This works good with xcode 4.3 und IOS 5. But know it doesn't scroll.

If I deactivate `Auto Layout` in the file inspector it works perfect.
But the layout in for iPhone 4 with the smaller display is not correct. The layout in iPhone 5 looks good.

What should I do, when I want don't to enable `Auto Layout`?

Answer (score 2):

Move this constrains to viewDidAppear. I just explained this issue on another question ([Autolayout Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747710/scrollview-xcode4-5-autolayou)).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
.....
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 830)];
....
}
```

Comment: Can you give me more details about your issue?

Comment: Here is detail of my issue. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237921/uiscrollview-when-autolayout-is-turned-on-storyboard)[/link]

Comment: Saw your post, I think you are overriding your settings with "addSubview". Let me know if I was right...