# UIScrollView when Autolayout is turned on (StoryBoard)

Tags: uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I was wrestling with UIScrollview and it knocked me out. 
I tried to take reference from following two post on stackOverFlow

[scrollview xcode4.5 autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747710/scrollview-xcode4-5-autolayout),
[Xcode 4.5 UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747603/xcode-4-5-uiscrollview),
[Embed ImageView in ScrollView with Auto Layout on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619786/embed-imageview-in-scrollview-with-auto-layout-on-ios-6),

I tried viewDidLayoutSubviews, as told in
[UIScrollView setContentSize breaks view with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439304/uiscrollview-setcontentsize-breaks-view-with-auto-layout) that is causing my app to crash.

And I tried ViewDidLoad, viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear but nothing worked. 
I tried google and found couple more related post 
https://coderwall.com/p/zfe8da, http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45113

I tried to rethink and didnt find anything fancy that I was not doing. It seems simple, straight approach.

I am out of clues or any guess please help me.

I am using following code, just to mentioned I have 3 images that I have put in the ScrollView. I have stack them on top of each other so there height is more than iPhone screen height. I was expecting it I set them just scroll simple, but guess I was wrong. 
***In Implementation file***

```
_howtoScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
_howtoScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.howtoScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.howtoScrollView.frame.size.width, 700)];
[self.view addSubview:_howtoScrollView];
```

***In interface file .h***

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *howtoScrollView;
```

Anyone who got success with ScrollView while having StoryBoard Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `_howtoScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);`, see if it works.

If you really need to change the frame of a view, in Autolayout, you should not set the frame  directly in your code, you should modify the `Constraint` instead.

Comment: Nope it does work either by commenting _howtoScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); line ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it without the "addSubview" function. I think that with AutoLayout override your other settings...

Answer (score 0):

Using interface builder,

expand your scroll view's Constraints section. Then select 'Horizontal Space Constraint'. Under that section you must be probably having a negative value for the 'constant' value. Change it to `0`. It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  Apple hid the explanation in the release notes.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0.  Look under the UIKit section.